# curl https://github.com fails with self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: ssl, curl

When I execute:

```
curl -L https://github.com
```

I get:

```
   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time
 Current
                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:--
 --:--:--     0 curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain More details here:
 https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

 curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could
 not establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this
 situation and how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned
 above.
```

Curl'ing eg. https://twitter.com works perfectly even thought it is verified as well by Kaspersky. I also already replaced the `cacert.pem` as suggested here - [why-cant-curl-properly-verify-a-certificate-on-windows](https://superuser.com/questions/442793/why-cant-curl-properly-verify-a-certificate-on-windows?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Additional:

```
curl --version

 curl 7.58.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) libcurl/7.58.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2n
 (WinSSL) zlib/1.2.11 libidn2/2.0.4 nghttp2/1.29.0 Release-Date:
 2018-01-24 Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps
 ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp Features: AsynchDNS
 Debug IDN IPv6 Largefile SSPI Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM SSL libz TLS-SRP
 HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy MultiSSL Metalink


curl -L -v https://github.com

* STATE: INIT => CONNECT handle 0x12bf160; line 1392 (connection #-5000)
* Rebuilt URL to: https://github.com/
* Added connection 0. The cache now contains 1 members
* STATE: CONNECT => WAITRESOLVE handle 0x12bf160; line 1428 (connection #0)   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time 
Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:--
--:--:--     0*   Trying 192.30.253.112...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* STATE: WAITRESOLVE => WAITCONNECT handle 0x12bf160; line 1509 (connection #0)
* Connected to github.com (192.30.253.112) port 443 (#0)
* STATE: WAITCONNECT => SENDPROTOCONNECT handle 0x12bf160; line 1561 (connection #0)
* Marked for [keep alive]: HTTP default
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt   CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22): } [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1): } [512 bytes data]
* STATE: SENDPROTOCONNECT => PROTOCONNECT handle 0x12bf160; line 1575 (connection #0) { [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2): { [109 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11): { [1920 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, Server hello (2): } [2 bytes data]
* SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
* Marked for [closure]: Failed HTTPS connection
* multi_done
* stopped the pause stream!   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
* The cache now contains 0 members
* Expire cleared curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain More details here:
https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could
not establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this
situation and how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned
above.
```

Comment: You may have an intercepting proxy. You first need to find out to which IP addresses does `github.com` resolve to, and then fetch/see what certificate you get, for example with: `openssl s_client -connect github.com:443 -servername github.com`. I get : `subject=/businessCategory=Private Organization/jurisdictionC=US/jurisdictionST=Delaware/serialNumber=5157550/C=US/ST=California/L=San Francisco/O=GitHub, Inc./CN=github.com` and you?

Comment: ok. it is my work laptop and hence the antivirus software kaspersky is installed. kaspersky inserts a proxy which adds a self signed certificate. thats why the request is failing.

Comment: So I guess you either totally trust this intercepting proxy and hence its certificate, or you just remove this component for all your HTTPS streams...

Comment: yes. by creating a `ca-all.pem` as suggested here: https://gist.github.com/olih/a50ce2181a657eefb041, I was able to execute `curl --cacert ~/Desktop/ca-all.pem -L https://github.com` successfully.

Comment: Technically not a problem indeed, you just have to understand you are giving all your plaintext traffic to some application, that may do what it wants with it, besides sending it to the true destination you wanted to reach. You have to decide if you trust this application to always do the right thing with all the private data supposedly exchanged inside a TLS stream.